# Find coordinates of N squares traveled in spiral matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I solved an [online judge problem](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/runs/code/16361229) (inputs are correct), however my algorithm is too slow.

I have a matrix of variable sizes, and want to find the coordinates of the `n` amount of squares *traveled*. In this example the size of the matrix is: ***`8`***. Meaning the amount of rows and columns.

[image]

Starting at point `x, y`: (1, 1) and;

- Going as far **right** as possible
- Going as far **down** as possible
- Going as far **left** as possible
- Going as far **up** as possible

Given that `i = 53`

Starting at `n = 0`and adding up `1`to `n`for each square traveled, by reaching `n == i` calculate the coordinates.

*What I have tried:*

(Disclaimer: I'm only posting this so you can see how naive I am)

In my original programming problem I have achieved it via creating a variable `m`with the size of the matrix so in this case `m = 8`, and deducing it after each `right`and `left`*movements*.

```
y = 0 //y will move first, starts offboard at imaginary column `0`
x = 1 //start from row 1
m = 8
right: { y+= i; m -= 1;} //x = 1, y = 8 / m = 7
down: {  x+= m; }//x = 8, y = 8
left: { y-= m; m -= 1; } //x = 8, y = 1 / m = 6
up: { x-=m; } // x = 2, y = 1
```

And iterating, until another created variable `sumofsteps`, to sum up the amount of `m` squares traveled reach `i` which is in this case `53`.''

This is, of course very naive, since in some cases the matrix can be as big as `1073741824` and the number of steps `1152921504603393520`, which in my program takes too long to solve.

The program run-time limit is 1.0 seconds for a single input.

Is there a faster way to find the coordinates?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void GetSpiralFinalCoordinates(
const unsigned long long gridSize, 
const unsigned long long finalDestSteps, 
unsigned long long& x, unsigned long long& y)
{
    x = 1;
    y = 0;
    unsigned long long stepsWalked{0};
    unsigned long long currentStepsToWalk = gridSize;
    enum movedir {RIGHT = 0, DOWN, LEFT, UP};

    while(stepsWalked < finalDestSteps)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if(stepsWalked + currentStepsToWalk < finalDestSteps)
            {
                stepsWalked += currentStepsToWalk;
                switch(i)
                {
                    case RIGHT: { y+= currentStepsToWalk; currentStepsToWalk -= 1;}break;
                    case DOWN: {  x+= currentStepsToWalk; }break;
                    case LEFT: { y-= currentStepsToWalk; currentStepsToWalk -= 1; }break;
                    case UP: { x-=currentStepsToWalk; }break;
                }
            } else {
                int lastAmountOfStepsToWalk = finalDestSteps - stepsWalked;
                switch(i)
                {
                    case RIGHT: { y+= lastAmountOfStepsToWalk; }break;
                    case DOWN: {  x+= lastAmountOfStepsToWalk; }break;
                    case LEFT: { y-= lastAmountOfStepsToWalk; }break;
                    case UP: { x-=lastAmountOfStepsToWalk; }break;
                }
                stepsWalked = finalDestSteps + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long x, y;
    unsigned long long a, b;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream issline(line);
    issline >> a;
    issline >> b;
    GetSpiralFinalCoordinates(a,b, x, y);
    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: TLE is for inefficient algorithms. A sure way to provoke it is to simulate the description instead of calculating the result. I think that is your problem. Try NOT to simulate the whole spiral. Try instead to spot the math behind. The result then is a few lines of code, maybe one. Simulation always gets you loops and counting.

Comment: Typically the online-judging question are designed such that an obvious brute force solution will work for the example/test data.  But a more optimal algorithm is need to solve the hidden test-cases either because of memory or time constraints.  Providing you the answer (if we can work it out) removes the point of these type of test.

Comment: @Yunnosch so it is really just a mathematical problem, not a programming challenge.

Comment: There is a clear pattern here if you can find it. Try different thing *on paper*, and see if you can find it.

Comment: As a hint about the pattern, follow the arrow in the image. Count the number of steps in each direction. Write down those numbers. Look at them closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the "perimeter" of the matrix. We can calculate the number of cells in the outer shell as

```
P0 = 2 * rows + 2 * cols - 4
```

If we consider the square of cells immediately inside, we can say

```
P1 = 2 * (rows - 2) + 2 * (cols - 2) - 4 = P0 - 8
```

So, until both sides are bigger then 1, we can find the sum of those values as

```
sumi = (i + 1) * P0 - 4 * i * (i + 1)
```

You can use those formulas to "peel" the outer part of the matrix, meaning, finding the value *i* such that

sum<sub>i</sub> < n < sum<sub>i+1</sub>

Then you can use the code you already have to walk through the last steps.

Comment: could not understand

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta Consider the example in your question, a 8x8 matrix. The number of squares that form its outer edges (what I called the perimeter) are **28** (= 2*8 +2*8 -4), while n is **53**. You can solve the last equation (or perform a binary search, avoiding possible overflows), maybe rewritten as `x*P - 4*x*(x-1) - 53 = 0` or `-4x^2 + x(P+4) - 53`, which has two solutions, **2.34** and 5.66 (too big, ignore it). This means that you can consider a smaller matrix of side **4** (= 8 - 2*2) with n = **5** (= 53 - 2*28 + 4*2), solvable with your method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a pattern.
You could start with this (you may have a problem of stack overflow for large value but it's easy to replace the recursion if you want to)

```
void GetSpiralFinalCoordinates(
    const unsigned long long s,
    const unsigned long long n,
    unsigned long long& x,
    unsigned long long& y) {

    // calculate max n for external ring 
    const unsigned long long maxN = s * 4 - 4;

    // if not in the external ring we will use recursion
    if (n > maxN) {
        unsigned long long subX;
        unsigned long long subY;
        GetSpiralFinalCoordinates(s - 2, n - maxN, subX, subY);
        x = subX + 1; 
        y = subY + 1;
        return;
    }
    if (n <= s) {
        x = n; 
        y = 1; 
        return;
    }
    if (n <= 2 * s - 1) {
        x = s; 
        y = n - s + 1;
        return;
    }
    if (n <= 3 * s - 2) {
        x = s - n + (2 * s - 1);
        y = s;
        return;
    }
    x = 1;
    y = 4 * s - n - 2; 
}
```